# Searching for column name when its stored as an id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table, where users can search data. They enter a search term and if it matches any of the table data results are returned.

This is the controller.

```
  $query = request('search-term');

      if(!empty($query))
      {
        $user = OnlineCounsellingApplication::where('name', 'like', $query)
                                              ->orWhere('email', 'like', $query)
                                              ->orWhere('country_id', 'like', $query)
                                              ->paginate(25)
                                              ->setPath('');}
```

If a user search an email, that email record will show up.

My issue is if a user searchers a country, no results are returned as I have countries stored as an id, which relates to a name on another table. It is stored as country_id. The record is initially displayed like so

```
  @foreach($users as $row)
      <tr>
        <td>{!! $row->id !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $row->name ?: 'No Name Provided'!!}</td>
        <td>{!! $row->email !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $row->country['name'] ?: 'No Country Provided' !!}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

How to I accept a string as input and search for it based on the id

Comment: try to use relation object `with(['country' => function($q) use ($name){
$q->where('name', $name)})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `orWhereHas` method. It will looks like

```
$searchTerm = request('search-term');

if(!empty($searchTerm)) {
    $user = OnlineCounsellingApplication::where('name', 'like', $searchTerm)
        ->orWhere('email', 'like', $searchTerm)
        ->orWhereHas('country', function ($query) use $searchTerm {
            $query->where('name', 'like', $searchTerm);
        })
        ->paginate(25)
        ->setPath('');
}
```